# Can I trust this Windows 10 WiFi fix?

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've just installed Windows 10, and I my laptop can't find any wireless networks, even though I know for certain that there are ones available. I did do a little research, and found that (supposedly) entering these two commands in the command prompt will fix the issue.

```
reg delete HKCR\CLSID\{988248f3-a1ad-49bf-9170-676cbbc36ba3} /va /f
netcfg -v -u dni_dne
```

Is this a good solution, or is there a better/safer solution?

Comment: Before blindly following the internet you must find the root cause of the problem first. Do you have latest driver, is **WLAN AutoConfig** service running ?

Comment: This knowledge base article from Microsoft contains the same instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had issue updating to Windows 10 from Windows 7 and then being unable to connect to WiFi.

My windows system is 32 bit, and when I entered the first reg edit command line as above, the prompt returned with ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

So don't know whether this will work for all units, unfortunately